# Duplicate Request in DoExpressCheckoutPayment (Digital Goods Checkout Express)

Tags: php, paypal

Long story short, I believe I've implemented the flow correctly, but on the final DoExpressCheckoutPayment I am getting:

```
ACK => SuccessWithWarning  
L_ERRORCODE0 => 11607
L_SHORTMESSAGE0 => Duplicate Request
L_LONGMESSAGE0 => A successful transaction has already been completed for this token
```

Is this simply because I'm doing a GetExpressCheckoutDetails request before this? (the GetExpressCheckoutDetails ACK is "Success")

Note that the other data returned from DoExpressCheckoutPayment looks good:

```
PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS => Completed
PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK => Success
```

Should I just look for PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK and ignore the rest?

Sidenote- In case it's of interest, I'm using the PHP lib at https://github.com/thenbrent/paypal-digital-goods though I changed the stuff in the examples return.php to GetExpressCheckoutDetails on a new class since, of course, it made no sense to use the same purchase data every time and it has to be dynamic

**EDIT:** Okay I'm baffled. If I *only* call the GetExpressCheckoutDetails, then the response is:

`CHECKOUTSTATUS => PaymentActionNotInitiated`

However, if I call GetExpressCheckoutDetails and then DoExpressCheckoutPayment, the response of the *preceding GetExpressCheckoutDetails* becomes:

`CHECKOUTSTATUS => PaymentActionCompleted` (and it follows that the result of the subsequent DoExpressCheckoutPayment has the error of Duplicate Request)

How does that even make sense?! Did vanilla PHP just become asynchronous? Has paypal allocated enough money to buy a time machine? I'm probably missing something very basic, but I really don't see it yet :\

**EDIT 2** Some Sample Code (didn't strip it to make it 100% vanilla, but should be pretty straightforward):

```
public static function completePaypalPurchase() {
    self::configurePaypal(''); // Not relevent, just some setting of API keys and stuff
    $paypalAPI = new PayPal_Purchase(); // Just to get purchase info so we can form the real purchase request
    $response = $paypalAPI->get_checkout_details(); // Uses token from GET automatically

    echo("RESPONSE FROM GET CHECKOUT");
    print_r($response);

    $ack = strtoupper($response['ACK']);
    $userID = (int)$response['CUSTOM']; // This was passed earlier and is retrieved correctly
    $numCredits = (int)$response['L_QTY0'];

    //NOTE: If I comment out the below, then the $response above has CHECKOUTSTATUS => PaymentActionNotInitiated
    //      BUT If I do not comment it out, leaving it as-is then the $response above has CHECKOUTSTATUS => PaymentActionCompleted
    //      That's the core of the problem and where I'm stuck

    if($ack == "SUCCESS" && $numCredits && $userID && $userID == $loggedInUserID) {
        $paypalAPI = self::getPaypalPurchaseCredits($userID, $numCredits); // This creates a new PayPal_Purchase() with this info. In fact, it's the same method and therefore should return the same sort of object as the one used at the beginning of the flow
        $response = $paypalAPI->process_payment();
        $ack = strtoupper($response['ACK']);

        echo("RESPONSE FROM DO PAYMENT");
        print_r($response);
        if(isset($response['PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID']) && $ack == "SUCCESS") {
            $transactionID = $response['PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID'];
            return(new APIReturn(true, array('ack'=>$ack, 'userid'=>$userID, 'numcredits'=>$numCredits, 'transactionid'=>$transactionID)));
        }
    }
    return(new APIReturn(false, self::ERROR_NORESULT));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct order the calls is SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails, and then DoExpressCheckoutPayment.  If you're geting a duplicate order error then you must be calling DECP twice somehow.  You need to step through your code and see exactly how that's happening.  It may be something in the class that you're using.

On that note, you may be interested in taking a [look at my class](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/) instead.  It makes everything very simple as it turns it all into PHP arrays and handles the gritty work for you.

If you don't want to start over with new class, though, then again, you need to step through what's happening with your code and through the class methods to see where it's getting posted twice.

Another thing I notice is that you're only checking for ACK = Success.  That means when ACK = SuccessWithWarning it'll be treated as a failure.  You need to handle both Success and SuccessWithWarning (which a decent class library would handle for you.)

Sorry I don't have a more definitive answer, but again, somewhere either in your code or in the library it must be getting posted twice.  Are you logging the raw API requests and responses along the way? If so you'd be able to confirm it's getting hit twice because you'd have 2 sets of DECP requests and responses logged.

Comment: Thanks. Since I am definitely not calling DoExpressCheckoutPayment twice, it must be some weird bug in the library. Since I'm only doing one thing- singular checkouts of digital goods via express checkout, I guess I'll try to roll my own and see where I end up. Will give your code a try if I get stuck again though.

Still- it seems very strange that the *preceding* call to GetExpressCheckoutDetails would fail :\

Comment: If you're going to "roll your own" that's a perfect time to use my library.  It doesn't try to do too much for you.  It just lays everything out so all you have to do is fill in parameters.  It has a separate template file for every Classic API call available in the PayPal platform and it will really save you loads of time.  I really recommend you take a look at it.  You can have a working Express Checkout setup done in about 10 min.

Comment: I decided to roll my own using the official paypal stuff and what I learned from playing with that other lib. I'm sure your library is fantastic, but I really want just some minimal code where I can easily see how it works in case I need to debug. Good news is I was successful :) Here's my classes sortof... I think leaving in my stubs for actual use case is helpful for anyone wanting to use it in production: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7925377

Comment: That doesn't look like minimal code to me, but I'm glad you got it working!  :)

Comment: Are you kidding? Your includes are around 7600 lines of code. Mine is 392  - and that includes some working abstraction and html example... much of which is comments! I can't imagine how it could be more minimal than that

Comment: My library is big because it includes every single API PayPal offers.  If you were to use it, though, even if you included every single parameter the DECP request, for example, it's only 130 lines, and that's mainly because all the arrays are split up into individual lines.  

The goal was to get your stuff working, and it sounds like you did, so that's good. No need to fuss over how it was done, but I'll still say if you plan on doing a lot with PayPal's API's in the future my library would help you save loads of time. Based on usage stats, thousands of other developers agree.  And it's free.